# Поиск по нескольким полям класса

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, статьи, примеры кода и т.п., где есть реализация или показано как правильно реализовывать поиск по нескольким параметрам, которые выбирает пользователь. 
У меня есть контейнер в котом хранятся объекты, которые содержат разные поля. Мне нужно находить объекты по полям (критериям), которые выберет пользователь.

Comment: Вопрос можно трактовать очень широко, вплоть до создания собственного движка базы данных. Пожалуйста уточните вопрос: Насколько вы свободны в выборе средств реализации? Обязательно разбирать запрос пользователю самостоятельно или можно подключить готовую реализацию? Нужен ли быстрый поиск, или достаточно перебора всего массива со сложностью O(n)? Какие типы запросов предполагаются? Нужна ли поддержка математических и строковых операций между полями? Нужны ли статистические запросы (top10, unique values,...)?

Answer (score 1):

Ну все просто. напиши пару функциональных объектов который займутся сравнением для поиска и все. Дальше отдайте все это в std::find_if а там пользователь выберет по чем искать (да хоть по 2 полям) и Вы подсунете нужный функциональный объект.

Вот банальный пример реализации.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


class Obj
{
public:
    Obj(int i, std::string s, int i2) : i(i), s(s), i2(i2){}

    int i;
    std::string s;
    int i2;
};


int main() {

    std::vector<Obj> v{{1, "aa", 11}, {2, "bb", 12}, {3, "cc", 13}};

    auto int_cmp{[](Obj& o, int i, int i2) ->bool {return (o.i == i && o.i2 == i2 ) ? true : false;}};

    auto it1{std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::bind(int_cmp, std::placeholders::_1 , 3, 13))};
    if (it1 != std::end(v)) {
        std::cout << "catch!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: все равно пока не понимаю как обработать различные случаи (их же будет очень много. Или пользователь решит по одному полю искать, или сразу по нескольким...). У вас я вижу поиск только по первому и третьему полю объекта. А как же все таки искать по-любым. (Понимаю, что вы скорее всего ответили на вопрос, но я первый раз таким занимаюсь и для меня это немного сложно и не понятно). Будьте добры подробнее объясните, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: @elvy если вы не понимаете, решайте задачу по этапно. На первом этапе найдите все элементы с 1 полем, скопируйте их во временный контейнер, потом в нем выполните поиск по 2ому и т.д. Затем осознайте, что это дикий костыль и трата по памяти, и начните думать об универсальном решении